# Using INNER JOIN when pulling info from two tables using WebMatrix/Razor

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I have written the following code to pull some information out of my database

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");
var propertyinfo = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo WHERE PropertyID='@0'";
var qpropertyinfo = db.QuerySingle(propertyinfo);
var ownerinfo = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM OwnerInfo WHERE OwnerID='2'";
var qownerinfo = db.QuerySingle(ownerinfo); 
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
@qpropertyinfo.PropertyName
@qownerinfo.FirstName
@qownerinfo.LastName
</body>
</html>
```

In both tables, there is a column called 'OwnerID', and I want to be able to pull the OwnerID from the PropertyInfo table and then show the FirstName and LastName of that owner from the OwnerID table. How do I do this, do I need to use an INNER JOIN statement?

I want it to be dynamic, so that when I change to a different property, the Owner Info changes too.

Comment: Yes you have to use an inner join.  If you don't know how, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 minutes.  For switching owners, make the owner id a query parameter like you did for the property id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should do what you require:

```
SELECT OwnerInfo.FirstName, OwnerInfo.LastName 
FROM OwnerInfo
INNER JOIN PropertyInfo on PropertyInfo.OwnerID = OwnerInfo.OwnerID
WHERE PropertyInfo.PropertyID='@0'
```

You can then pass in the PropertyId as a parameter as you have done in your question.

Comment: And Dan, thanks for the advice about the book, i might have to invest :p